# Why does the program skip taking input when function is called?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am writing a simple C++ program that takes the the student information and their marks in the different subjects.

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H_
#define STUDENT_H_
#include<string>


class Student {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string dept;
    unsigned char age;
    std::string usn;
public:
    Student();
    void getinfo();
    void display();
    virtual ~Student();
};


 class Score:public Student {
 private:
     int math;
     int sci;
     int chem;
     int english;
     int SS;
 public:
     void marks();
     void dispscore();
     Score();

};

 #endif /* STUDENT_H_ */
```

The above is the header file.

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 Student::Student()
{
 age = 0x00;
}

Student::~Student()
{

}
 Score::Score()
 {
     math = 0x00;
     sci = 0x00;
     chem = 0x00;
     SS = 0x00;
     english = 0x00;
 }

 void Student::getinfo()
 {
     cout<<"Enter the Students Name: "<<endl;
     getline(cin,name);
     cout<<"Enter Department--> "<<endl;
     getline(cin,dept);
     cout<<"Enter USN--> "<<endl;
     getline(cin,usn);
     cout<<"Enter Age--> "<<endl;
     cin>>age;
 }

 void Student::display()
 {
     cout<<name<<endl;
     cout<<dept<<endl;
     cout<<usn<<endl;
     cout<<age<<endl;
 }

 void Score::marks()
  {
     cout<<"Enter Math Score: "<<endl;
     cin>>math;
     cout<<"Enter Science Score: "<<endl;
     cin>>sci;
     cout<<"Enter Chemistry Score:  "<<endl;
     cin>>chem;
     cout<<"Enter English Score: "<<endl;
     cin>>english;
     cout<<"Enter the Social Studies Score: "<<endl;
     cin>>SS;

 }

  void Score::dispscore()
 {
     cout<< math << endl;
     cout<<sci<<endl;
     cout<<chem<<endl;
     cout<<english<<endl;
     cout<<SS<<endl;

 }

 int main()
 {
     Score s;
     s.getinfo();
     s.marks();
     s.display();
     s.dispscore();


 }
```

The above is the cpp file. When compiled, I get the output as shown below and facing the following problems, they are:
1. Skips taking the input score for Math and directly starts from taking input score for science,
2. The age entered is 23, however in the console, it does not display it as "23" but as 2 on one line and 3 on the next line as seen in the output - > Is this happening because I press enter?.

```
Enter the Students Name: 
Smith Diaz
Enter Department--> 
ECE
Enter USN--> 
4So08ec112
Enter Age--> 
23
Enter Math Score: 
Enter Science Score: 
77
Enter Chemistry Score:  
66
Enter English Score: 
89
Enter the Social Studies Score: 
57
Smith Diaz
ECE
4So08ec112
2
3
77
66
89
57
```

Comment: `cin` leaves you with a ``\n`` for the next `getline()` operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`age` has type `unsigned char`, so `cin` read only one character and stored it there.

Try changing the type of member `age` to `int`.

Comment: I changed the type from char to int and It solved both the problems. Thanks!